# Forming an interval of rational dimensions with volume small

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $C=\prod_{i=1}^n[a_i,b_i]$. Show that there exists $J\supseteq C$ with rational dimensions such that $0\le vol(J)-vol(C)<\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0.$

So what I have tried so far is constructing $J$:

Let $d_i=b_i-a_i$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $p_i\in [d_i,d_i+\varepsilon]\cap\Bbb Q$. Let $J=\prod_{i=1}^n [a_i,a_i+p_i]$. Hence, $J$ has rational dimensions and $J\supseteq C$. But how do I find an appropriate $\varepsilon>0$ that validates the volume property. We know that $$vol(J)=\prod_{i=1}^np_i\le \prod_{i=1}^n(d_i+\varepsilon),$$
but from there I'm not sure how to proceed to get that it is less than or equal to $vol(C)+\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$ f(u) = \prod_{i=1}^n(d_i+ u) $$
is a *continuous* function, since it is a polynomial.

So given any $\varepsilon > 0$, it is possible to find a sufficiently small $u > 0$ such that
$$ \left| \prod_{i=1}^n(d_i+ u) - \prod_{i=1}^nd_i \right| < \varepsilon $$

You've already described how to construct a $J$ with rational dimensions such that
$$  \prod_{i=1}^nd_i  \leq vol(J) \leq \prod_{i=1}^n(d_i+ u) $$

This $J$ then satisfies
$$  \left| vol(J) - vol(C) \right| = \left| vol(J) - \prod_{i=1}^nd_i \right| < \varepsilon $$
which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $M$ be the maximum of $1,d_1,d_2,...,d_n$. Check that $\prod_{i=1}^n(d_i+\varepsilon)\leq \prod_{i=1}^n d_i+(2M)^{n}\epsilon$ (if $0<\epsilon <1$) by expanding the product. [See how may terms are there in the expansion excluding the term $\prod_{i=1}^n d_i$ and see what a bound for each term is].

Answer (score 2):

$$\prod_{i=1}^n(d_i+\varepsilon)=P(\varepsilon)$$
polynomial hence continuous, and
$$P(0)=vol(C).$$ Hence you can make $vol(J)$ as close to $vol(C)$ as you want by taking $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small.

Edit: Kenny Wong just detailed this argument.